# Excel comparing two columns, complicated matching

Tags: excel, match

I have 3 columns: A, B, C. A and B are strings and C are integers. I wish to compare columns A and B. If an entry of A1 is found to be anywhere in B, then I wish to check the contents of A in the row where B is found to be the same. If A of that row is the same string as the B1 (B of the row where we started our search), then check C1, and C where B is found. Return the lower value of the C's.

For example:

```
Header     Column A   Column B   Column C  
Row 1      AAA        DFD        1
Row 2      BBB        LAX        1
Row 3      DFD        AAA        3
Row 4      444        DDD        5
```

If I compare A1 with B, it will return 1 (min of 1,3 ) since A1 matches with B3 and A3 matches with B1. I'm not sure how to write this function out on excel. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Excel 2007 or later, and that your table is in A1:C5 (with headers in row 1), enter this formula in D2:

```
=IFERROR(MIN(C2,INDEX($C$2:$C$5,MATCH(B2&"|"&A2,INDEX($A$2:$A$5&"|"&$B$2:$B$5,,),0))),"")
```

Copy down as required.

Your example didn't contain any empty cells in column C, so in making this solution I have presumed that this is not possible. (In any case, what would be the "minimum" of a blank and a number?)

Also, you didn't mention what the result should be in cases for rows where your criteria are *not* satisfied, so I presumed a blank would suffice.

Comment: How did you go about writing this? I would really like to learn how to do it myself...